# Como criar subpastas para as Api no asp.net webapi?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Por padrão, a pasta é Controllers

Eu gostaria de criar outras subpastas

Controllers -> Api -> OutraPasta/ Outrapasta2 etc

Como faço isso? e como configura o router para isso?

Answer (score 1):

A única coisa que me veio no momento é a criação de Area, como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dentro do `Controller` da **Area** *Voto* tem um `DadosController` que é um `WebApi`, segue o código:

```cs
public class DadosController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/<controller>/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/<controller>
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/<controller>/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/<controller>/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

Executando da mesma forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As configurações de rota nesse caso já estão feitas automaticamente quando criar a ***Area***. Para usar também se não for elaborado nenhum nomenclatura de rota diferente fica do jeito que está no arquivo exemplo: `GET api/<controller>`, seguindo o modelo padrão.